# firebase firestore rules not working as expected "allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

It's my first time setting up security rules in firestore and I want to make it so authenticated users only have access. I'm using firebase custom auth for my auth system.

Firebase security rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
     allow write: if false; 
     allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId; 
     }
  }
}
```

my database schema is `./users/{userId}/...` I only want users to have access to their specific collection in the database.

The *write* rule is false so only my backend server with admin privileges can write

With these rules my client side code is throwing the error `FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.` when I try to make a call to read.

If it matters I'm making a next.js app and using the standard Web Version 9 (modular) firestore functions

EDIT: I changed the rules to this, still getting the same error...

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the client-side code that is trying to read the document?

Comment: Are you sure the user is authenticated before fetching the doc?

Comment: @hangindev.com 
```
const getUserInfo = async () => {
    const docRef = doc(db, "users", auth.user.uid);
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);  
    if (docSnap.exists()) {
        const data = [
            {account: docSnap.data()}
        ]
        setDocData(data);
    } else {
      console.log("No such document!");
    }
}
useEffect(() => {
    if (!auth.user) return;
    getUserInfo();
    }, [auth.user]);
```

Comment: @RenaudTarnec yes, I have a useEffect call that is 
```
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!auth.user) return;
        getUserInfo();
    }, [auth.user]);
```
With getUserInfo(); being the function that makes the call to read data from firebase

Comment: Also if I change the read rule to ```allow read: if 1 == 1;```, it still fails

Comment: Can you change `match /users/{userId}` to `match /users/{userId}/{document=**}` and try?